# putting html tags around matches in a string

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I've been looking for an answer but could not find one for my specific use case: I am trying make all matches (coming from the dictionary object) in a string appear green thanks to HTML tags.

In particular there's a case I have not found a way to solve (explained after my code).

```
var data = "cat fish";

var dictionary = {
    "regex1": "cat",
    "regex2": "cat fish"
}


function buildColoredString(data, dictionary) {
    var coloredString = data;

    for (var prop in dictionary) {
        var toReplace = new RegExp(dictionary[prop].regex, "g");
        var newString = "<b style='color: green;'>" + dictionary[prop].regex + "</b>";
        coloredString = coloredString.replace(toReplace, newString);
    }

    console.log(coloredString);
}
```

When running buildColoredString I only get "cat" to be surrounded by the HTML tags but not "cat fish" since it's not matching due to the HTML tags being now present in the string I am building. Any idea how to solve that and get "cat" & "cat fish" surrounded by the HTML tags (I don't mind if there are 'too many' tags rendering some of them useless from a visual standpoint.

Thanks for your help, have a nice day!

Answer (score 2):

Sort your dictionary by size of `String`. Do "cat fish" first then "cat" second...

Answer (score 0):

You could simply run the `cat fish` regex replacement first. Here the "**dictionary**" is converted to a **list** to preserve order.

You can also use `$1` to reference the matched text:

```
var data = "cat fish";

var arr = [
    "cat fish",
    "cat",
]


function buildColoredString(data, arr) {
    var coloredString = data;

    for (var regex in arr) {
        var toReplace = new RegExp("(" + arr[regex] + ")", "g");
        var newString = "<b style='color: green;'>$1</b>";
        coloredString = coloredString.replace(toReplace, newString);
    }

    console.log(coloredString);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As `cat fish` contains `cat`, you need to search for them at the same time, the longer first.

You can do it by putting the strings you wish to highlight in an array like Martin suggested, but use them in the **same** group separating them with `|`.

```
var arr = [
    "cat fish",
    "cat",
];

function buildColoredString(data, arr) {
    var coloredString = data;
    var replaceGroups = arr.join('|');

    var toReplace = new RegExp("(" + replaceGroups + ")", "g");
    var newString = "<b style='color: green;'>$1</b>";
    coloredString = coloredString.replace(toReplace, newString);

    console.log(coloredString);
};
```

I provided a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8wcrq7k3/) that surrounds both `cat` and `cat fish` with tags in the same sentence without overlapping.